# problema con form usando method POST

Tags: html5, post

Ando empezando en HTML y Tengo problemas al querer ejecutar un un formulario con el metodo post, lo mas raro es que si funciona con method get, alguna solución?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Area de Texto</title>


</head>

<body>
    <form action="/basico/2_listas.html" method="post">
        <h3>Introduce tu comentario</h3>
        <textarea name="comentario" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Escribe aqui"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que indica la pantalla es http405 que significa método no permitido, en este caso tu servidor no acepta el método POST.
La solución pasa por:

1. Usa un archivo php para procesar los datos. Con html no vas a poder. Los datos son vistos por PHP en la variable $_POST[identificador], donde identificador es el nombre del campo en el formulario.
2. Si aún recibes el mismo error comprueba que en la configuración de tu servidor no esté  AllowMethods GET OPTIONS
   Para permitir POST:  AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS
   Normalmente si tu servidor permite ejecución de código los métodos GET y POST estarán admitidos (es la opción por defecto). Entiendo que usas un servidor Apache.

Comment: Ando iniciando Html puro, nada de php ni apache, solo extensiones del visual studio, pero muchas gracias por la recomendacion, la tomare muy en cuenta